# Embedded arrays in MongoDB with CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb, cakephp

I'm building a service where I make use of the MongoDB. Backend-side, I use the CakePHP framework.
I have the following set:
A user model,for users,which is saved as json in mongodb. One user's record is called interests,which requires an embedded array with json data. The structure is the following:

```
{
'username' => 'something',
'password' => 'hashed_something',
'...' => '...',
'interests' => {
                 {
                  'id' => 1,
                  'name' => 'sports'
                  }
                     {
                  'id' => 2,
                  'name' => 'music'
                  }
                     {
                  'id' => 3,
                  'name' => 'cinema'
                  }
                }
}
```

So my question now is how could I code on that? I mean, how using the cakephp framework would I be able to put data into this embedded array and maybe edit (with PUT requests) them?

What i've thought till now is with something like this:

```
$this->request->data['User']['interests'][1] = $this->data['sports'];
$this->request->data['User']['interests'][2] = $this->data['music'];
```

But that doesn't feel very right to me..

Please, any suggestions are very welcomed

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does interest are further govern by some collection or they are just simple text?

Comment: there is a collection of interests, which contains all interests in JSON format (in mongodb). And I need to assign interests to users..

Comment: what do mean by $this->request->data['User']['interests'][1] = $this->data['sports']; line, what you are trying to accomplish using this line?

Comment: first of all i have to say that this code does NOT work. What i'm trying to accomplish is to add interests to the user. For example,i'm trying to add at the 1st record one interest,at the 2nd another one and at the Nnd record the last one interest that this user has. I cannot imagine the code that could achieve this,so please feel free to suggest me a working one,if you can.

Comment: that depend on how you getting interests from post array. add full post array in the question and i will answer your question

Comment: i'm not sure if i get what you asked me for,but i'm handling the posted data like this: $this->request->data..

Comment: Another solution I thought is the usage of HABTM relationship between the two collections..what do you think of this?

Comment: I asked about post data I mean from where you are getting interests of user and then saving to db. HABTM relationship? no make separate queries for all type of queries like save, update and delete. No relationship required...